# How can I outfit my hunter with armor?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

For the life of me I can't remember how to add equipment or armor to my hunter. It has been a while since I've last played *Dwarf Fortress*, and I have put together a set of leather armor that I would like my hunter to wear.

Comment: Afaik you do it from the uniform menu in the army-related interface (haven't played the game for too long), but I'm not entirely sure, since I never got that far into the game o_e

Comment: @user1337 I always start the game with a hunter fisher and farmer.

Comment: Why would you start with 3 food sector professions?

Comment: @mennoGouw more situational for me then that. I don't put points in professions before an embark I use the points to get dogs/cats and other more important items, I decide what they do by what their personality and physical traits determine them to be best at. if I am lucky enough to have everything I need and still able to get the early hunter fisher farmer I will. hunter more for defense from herds of badgers, the occasional bear and other thieving animals. fisher for the variety and shells and farmer for the stable food/drink supply.

Comment: @MennoGouw or you start with 7 miners, dig out the important parts, abandon & reclaim, and BAM, you have a fortress on day 1

Comment: I'd rather start out with some good starting profesions to create wealth so more migrants come in sooner and with armor/weapon smithing there is less steel to waste befor you reach the higher tier weapons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a hunter should pick up a leather armor by itself like he does with a crossbow. However you could draft him into military and assign him any weapon and armor which he will be using for hunting when he has no military duties.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually impossible right now due to this bug: http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=1451